# does consumer key or access token taken it twitter password is changes?

Tags: java, twitter4j

i am using twitter 4j API

my application used to work fine

but now when i try to update my status using my application i get this error

```
SEVERE: Failed to get timeline: 
403:
The request is understood, but it has been refused. 
An accompanying error message will explain why. 
This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
{"errors":[{"message":"SSL is required","code":92}]}
```

while i am trying to figure out what really did cause it

```
has it something to do with SSL ??
```

mean while can somebody please assure me whether password change for your twitter account affects the following or not ??

```
1. oauth.consumerSecret

2. oauth.consumerKey

3. oauth.accessToken

4. oauth.accessTokenSecret
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Twitter4J, but the way OAuth works is, no, it doesn't affect the token or secret. You can revoke access to an application, and that will revoke the token. Some services will automatically revoke all tokens when you change your password. I just changed my Yahoo password and it revoked Flikr. I don't think, but am not certain, that Twitter does that.

The error says SSL required. So you have to access the API via HTTPS://.

Comment: thanx for you quick help ma'am , i totally agree with your suggestion , I just was not able to resolve that , thus wantes to make sure that this wasn't a part of the issue , thanx again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had been using Twitter4J 3.0.3. I resolved it by upgrading to 3.0.6.